# Summing cells that contain multiple pieces of data within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to sum all cells that contain a time within 18:00 and 00:00, but the cells I'm referencing contain both a data and time in the same cells.

The cells I'm referencing look like this:

```
9/15/2020 19:23
9/18/2020 16:35
9/14/2020 17:24
9/14/2020 18:25
9/15/2020 16:41
9/15/2020 20:30
```

Is it possible to sum cells like this, or would the date and time need to be in separate cells in order to sum?

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, use:

```
=sumproduct(--(timevalue(right(A1:A6,5))<=timevalue("18:00")))
```

[image]

*(in this case Excel and Google Sheets are the same)*

**EDIT#1:**

The formula above will only work if the data cells are **text**.  If they are true Excel dates, then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6-INT(A1:A6)<=TIMEVALUE("18:00")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm doing this in Excel and I'm getting a #Value! error. Following the Calculation Steps, it errors out when it does the first time value. It looks like this:

    SUMPRODUCT(--({#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}<=TIMEVALUE("18:00")))

Comment: @slimofthejimz  ***MY ERROR***                       please see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot Gary!

Comment: @slimofthejimz I apologize for the original error.